# What does the number beside the "review question" link mean?

Tags: support

I noticed today when I was reviewing posts on the "review" page that the posts under the "low quality posts" link all have a number beside them.

When I hover over the number, it says "calculated quality score".

What does this mean? I am assuming a higher number is probably better, but what purpose does it solve? Is it just a way to sort posts into "better" and "worse" quality?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [what sjohnston said](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3469/1925), each post starts out with a score of 100 and posts appear in Review when their score drops below 80 according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76033/155160).

So, you're right - a higher number is better and the purpose of the score is just to display the relative quality of a post based on the automated heuristics that sjohnston linked to. It's not a number you really have to act on in any way when reviewing posts. It's just there for a little bit of additional information on how bad the system thinks it is. The lower the score, the more attention (read: editing) a post might need to become acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

A quality algorithm is run on new posts (maybe only first posts?) to try and catch the really awful ones. Posts containing certain words, phrases, punctuation, etc. have their score reduced, and if it is below a certain threshold, it shows up in this list.

See [Heuristics for detecting a bad answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer).

Comment: So that number reflects the algorithm? Am I right in assuming a higher number is better?

Comment: @AshleyNunn Yes, that number is the "score" that the post received based on that algorithm, and higher does appear to be better. I'm not positive, but from what I've seen previously, I think anything below 100 goes in the review list. Of course, since we don't know the exact details of the algorithm, the precise number doesn't mean a whole lot.